# PHP info->file tries to use 5gb memory

Tags: php, symfony

When calling Symfony's Uploadfile->getMimeType() on a csv file with 1100 rows and 60 columns and ~400kb size, $finfo->file tries to use around 5gb memory which gives me the following error:

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1077936128 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4294937911 bytes) in /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/MimeType/FileinfoMimeTypeGuesser.php on line 69

This is the part of code that gives that error:

```
if (!$finfo = new \finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE, $this->magicFile)) {
    return;
}

return $finfo->file($path);
```

Btw this happens on our production server that has PHP version 5.4, but doesn't happen on my dev server with php 7.

Comment: The path string of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in php 5.4 (already fixed in 2015, so you really should upgrade the php version in your server) that cause `finfo::file` function to allocate huge amounts of memory when trying to extract the info of a csv file.

Here is the link to the bug:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69224